# Android login/logout flow with the new SplashScreen API

Tags: android, android-12, android-splashscreen

I'm using the new SplashScreen API for android 12 but I'm a bit confused on the login flow now. I have one activity and multiple fragments as advised by google , the mainActivity is where the splashScreen launches and the user's supposed to be directed to either login fragment or the homefragment.
my question is how do I implement this work flow with the new SplashAPI? What fragment should be the startDestination? I don't want to use the popTo attribute since it doesn't look pretty to always show the loginfragment and then direct the user to Homefragment.
If someone could explain this to me I'd be grateful.

Comment: i think you must change your nav graph start destination when user  login

Answer (score 0):

Homefragment should be the startDestination. Conditionally navigate to loginfragment and pop back to Homefragment after authentication.
Refer to the following video by Ian Lake.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09qjn706ITA

Comment: should the condition be in the homefragment or the mainActivity while the splash screen is loading?

Comment: condition should be in homeFragment

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for that you can set the content of the activity after you check if the user is authorized or not and save the user state in a ViewModel or something, then set your content upon this state.

I leverage the power of `setKeepOnScreenCondition` function from `core-splashscreen` library.

[SplashInstaller.kt](https://gist.github.com/IAmShaarawy/30f5d285e1a9812ab6859b1ad63ff780)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        SplashInstaller(
            activity = this,
            beforeHide = {
                // Check if logged in or not asyncrounsly
                delay(2000)
            },
            afterHide = {
                setContent()
                // start with you desired destination up on the check you did in beforeHide
            })
    }
```

```
/**
 * @author Mohamed Elshaarawy on Oct 14, 2021.
 */
class SplashInstaller<A : ComponentActivity>(
    private val activity: A,
    visibilityPredicate: () -> Boolean = { BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE != "debug" },
    private val beforeHide: suspend A.() -> Unit = { delay(2000) },
    private val afterHide: A.() -> Unit
) : CoroutineScope by activity.lifecycleScope {

    private val isSplashVisibleChannel by lazy { Channel<Boolean>() }

    private val isAfterCalled by lazy { Channel<Boolean>(capacity = 1) }

    private val splashSuspensionJob = launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        activity.beforeHide()
        isSplashVisibleChannel.send(false)
    }

    init {
        if (visibilityPredicate()) {
            splashSuspensionJob.start()
            installSplash()
        } else afterSplash()
    }

    private fun installSplash() {
        activity.installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            val isVisible = isSplashVisibleChannel.tryReceive().getOrNull() ?: true
            if (!isVisible) {
                afterSplash()
            }
            isVisible
        }
    }

    private fun afterSplash() {
        if (isAfterCalled.tryReceive().getOrNull() != true) {
            isAfterCalled.trySend(true)
            activity.afterHide()
        }
    }
}
```

This solution uses

`androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01`

`androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0`

`org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2`

Comment: looks very interesting! Could you explain your code?